# NASA Apollo 11 fuel used to land on the moon

Tags: rockets

To land on the surface of the moon required the lander to descent onto the lunar surface. How much rocket fuel was used to descend to the surface of the moon?

Comment: Duplicate (repost) of [Apollo 11 space mission](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35445/apollo-11-space-mission)

Comment: This is a (somewhat unintentional?) repost of the same question from yesterday. Considering the number of comments the OP posted there as accidental answers, it looks like you might benefit from slowing down a bit and familiarizing yourself with how to use the site. You can [take the tour](https://space.stackexchange.com/tour) and also [visit the help center](https://space.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more.

Comment: It's not a dupe. The previous question asked about insertion into lunar orbit, this one is asking about descent from lunar orbit to surface.

Comment: That said, @carleto, you may want to take a look at [How do we know the Apollo Moon landings are real](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28172/195) before going much further with this line.

Comment: Related: [How was reserve fuel calculated for the Apollo missions?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2493/195)

Comment: "most of the fuel in the descent stage."

Comment: I voted against reopening - the OP's continuous questions in comments show what they are trying to get from these, and it isn't real answers.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apollo By The Numbers](https://georgetyson.com/files/apollostatistics.pdf), the LM descent stage for Apollo 11 started with 8248 kg of propellant (fuel + oxidizer), and consumed 7899 kg of it in descent. 3050 kg of that was Aerozine-50 fuel, the rest nitrogen tetroxide oxidizer.

Additional equipment was added to later Apollo missions, so the LMs tended to get progressively heavier, and so used more fuel on descent; Apollo 15 used the most, at 8334 kg of 8873 kg loaded.

Comment: A15? 8873 kg of propellant loaded, plenty of margin.

Comment: My calculations show the amount of fuel required to land on the surface of the moon using descent rocket is 250,000 lb using a lander moon wt of 2,500 lb yet the according to NASA the lander contains 18,000 kg of fuel.

Comment: Then there’s something quite wrong with your calculations. Since you haven’t told us anything about them, it’s impossible for us to tell you where you’ve gone wrong.

Comment: How much fuel does it take to launch a 2,500 lb lay load into the earth's orbit?

Comment: BBC did a doc stating that the Apollo 11 was a hoax.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsvQDCXWICo

Comment: It wasn’t a hoax. https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28172/195

Comment: How much fuel was used to decelerate the CSML at the moon.

Comment: That’s a separate question that you’ve already asked. The answers are also given in the resource I linked here, Apollo By The Numbers. The Space Stack Exchange community, on the whole, believes in the Apollo landings and you will make yourself very unwelcome if you continue pushing hoaxer theories. If there are particular aspects of the Apollo program you don’t understand, we’re happy to address your questions.

Comment: That is not a BBC documentary @carleto

Comment: ... it is Bart Sibrel's "[A funny thing happened on the way to the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Funny_Thing_Happened_on_the_Way_to_the_Moon)" @carleto